# Connecting to Internet Through Another Computers Connection

Tags: server, command-line, internet, connection

I have an old laptop running Ubuntu 10.10 (server edition) that I want to connect to the Internet, but it's Wireless card isn't working properly, so on the recommendation by a friend, I tried to connect to my Desktop (Windows XP) through Ethernet, and connect to the Internet through that, but the old guides I can find are for the Desktop edition of Ubuntu (e.g. GUI-based), and I don't know enough about the Terminal to figure it out on my own.

Are there any good guides then, on how to configure Ubuntu to connect like this, strictly through Terminal commands?

Comment: Do you want to give the laptop internet connection from the desktop or the opposite?

Comment: Give the laptop (Ubuntu) the Desktop (Windows) connection.

Comment: So you want to give the laptop internet from Windows. You need two network adapters on the desktop - one for receiving internet connection from your adapter (wire or wireless) and the other for the wired connection to laptop.

Comment: The desktop has a dedicated Wireless card, and then an internal Ethernet card. I'm more looking towards instructions on connecting to the network from Ubuntu, via terminal though.

Comment: In my experience, any ethernet plug supplying internet connection is automatically configured on connection. But if you want to set up a server accessible by Windows, you need to install `samba` and configure it accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, the main goal is for me to be able to ssh into the server, and to use it as a local web-server for development. -
I assume then, since it doesn't allow me to ssh / ping (server runs Apache) the server after I connect the Ethernet cables, that I'll need samba then?

Comment: No, I recommended `samba` because I thought you wanted to use it as a simple storage machine or something. If you know the `ssh` stuff (I don't), then you simply need to set your Ubuntu for them. From Windows you only need to share internet connection to the router (just Google). If you don't know the `ssh` stuff, edit and update your question to be more specific of your needs.

Comment: I don't know much about SSH. I've only ever used it to send commands to my laptop (Ubuntu), as some of the keys have broken off (it's an old laptop, I got it from my brother when he bought his Macbook). -- The server itself is running a LAMP stack, so I have a dedicated box, rather than loading up XAMPP everytime I want to test something.

Comment: Update your question to ask about setting up SSH for your needs. Internet connection is as simple as connecting cables, so your only headache would be SSH.

Comment: Well I've just now gotten it to work. I had to do a clean install of Ubuntu, and it works perfectly now.

Comment: Congratulations, how about you post your own answer and accept it?

Comment: I could do that, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If your ubuntu machine has the internet connectivity:

1. right click the network manager applet.
2. go to "edit connections".
3. In the wired tab select the the ethernet connection between the two
   comps that should be there if you've
4. connected the computers with the
   cable.
5. click 'edit'.
6. under ipv4 settings, change dhe method to "share with other
   computers"

Comment: I don't have access to a GUI. I'm running the Server Edition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to solve this completely, but as a workaround you could set up a proxy server on the Windows machine. Then, configure your network-aware programs on the Ubuntu machine to use the proxy server.