# How do I share my wlan0 internet connection to eth0 using command line and config files?

Tags: wireless, iptables, wpa-supplicant, ebtables

I understand how it is done using the GUI ([1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33070/connecting-to-internet-through-another-computers-connection), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169473/sharing-connection-to-other-pcs-via-wired-ethernet), [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3063/share-wireless-connection-with-wired-ethernet-port?lq=1)), but I need to do MANUALLY using linux command (iptables, ebtables ...).

I have been struggling with this for days, and I can seem to get it right.

What are the configuration steps and commands to use, considering that `wlan0` is connected to the internet?

Comment: check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing) out,
ubuntu gateway method, is this what u seeking?